# Laravel - can't save morphToMany relation in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following 2 models in a morphToMany relationship: Company and Tag

```
    public function tags(){
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable');
    }
    public function companies(){
    return $this->morphedByMany(Company::class, 'taggable');
    }
```

and I have the following working action to save 1 tag to 1 company:

```
   public function addTag($request){
        $company = Company::find($request->company_id);
        $company->tags()->syncWithoutDetaching($request->tag_id);
        return response()->json($company->tags, 201); 
    }
```

now I'm trying to do the same thing with many companies and many tags and it is not working. I've tried "syncWithoutDetaching", "saveMany", passing in an array of integers or strings, I keep getting this error:

```
 BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::tags does not exist. in file /home/vagrant/.../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php on line 100
```

This is the function I am using:

```
        public function  multiCompanyAddTags($request){

        $tags = $this->createManyRecords('App\AppSections\CRM\Models\Tag', $request->new_tags);
        $tagIDs = $tags->map(function ($item, $key) { return $item->id;
        });

        foreach ($request->companies as $key=>$id) 
        {  
            $company = Company::with(['notes','tags','contacts','tasks'])->find($id);

            $company->tags()->syncWithoutDetaching($tagIDs);

            return response()->json($company, 201); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Can `$request->company_id` be an array of multiple ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone pointed me to the answer: When calling $company = Company::with... in my loop, the call returns a collection and not the company.

I then need to call the first item of the collection to access the company, like so:

```
$company[0]->tags()->syncWithoutDetaching($tagIDs);
```

Comment: Find usually brings back a singleton unless $id is an array then yes it will be a collection. find(1) vs find([1]) will cause that issue?
What does a dump of $request->companies look like?